# Saving Animation with matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have installed ffmpeg using homebrew.

However the problem I am facing now is that no animation is saved when running the script. 
I have included below my script and my .bash_profile

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TKAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
  line.set_data([], [])
  return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
  x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
  y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
  line.set_data(x, y)
return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that
# the video can be embedded in html5.  You may need to adjust this for
# your system: for more information, see
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30)
```

.bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/../../usr/local/Celler/ffmpreg/2.2.2/bin
export FFMPEG_BIN=/$HOME/../../usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.2.2/bin/
```

Comment: No errors? are you sure you ale looking in the right directory for the output?

Comment: Would that apply to my Path or my PythonPath? My Path is set correctly.

Comment: It it's going to save into the cwd of the python instance that runs the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get output the animation correctly by Using an ipython notebook with the Anaconda environment.

There was a bit of a work around needed to get the animation to be displayed in the ipython notebook. Here it is:

```
from matplotlib import animation 
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

VIDEO_TAG = """<video controls>
 <source src="data:video/x-webm;base64,{0}" type="video/webm">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>"""

def anim_to_html(anim):
 if not hasattr(anim, '_encoded_video'):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.webm') as f:
        anim.save(f.name, fps=6, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libvpx'])
        video = open(f.name, "rb").read()
    anim._encoded_video = video.encode("base64")

return VIDEO_TAG.format(anim._encoded_video)

from IPython.display import HTML

def display_animation(anim):
  plt.close(anim._fig)
  return HTML(anim_to_html(anim))
```

Once the above code was in place, the following animation was output correctly into the ipython notebook:

```
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
  line.set_data([], [])
  return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
  x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
  y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
  line.set_data(x, y)
  return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

display_animation(anim)
```

For some reason when I right click and save I am unable to view the movie in a readable format...if anyone knows or figures out the solution to this please let me know!